# Image returning 404 Error in dockrized Laravel App. Image stored in volumes

Tags: laravel, docker

I have dockerized a Laravel application. All of the application works fine except for the images (stored in the storage directory) returns 404 Error.

I have shared the storage folder in (docker) volumes like this:

```
volumes: - ./storage:/var/www/storage
```

I am not sure if it is Laravel's problem or Docker container config. Has anyone encountered this problem before?